# Reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 LTS without losing data

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

My system consists of a NUC with two 1 TB SSDs running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The system is experiencing difficulty during boot-up, although the memory test shows no errors.

Currently, the `/home` directory is on one drive while the OS is on another.

How can I reinstall Ubuntu without losing any data? Is it safe to assume that the OS drive has no essential data that needs to be kept?

During boot it seems to be caught in a loop: monitor briefly showing signal loss, occasionally  the lighted keyboard blinks off then on, the disc load light blinks repeatedly, and sometimes an app supposed to communicate with my phone is trying as if the system has loaded, but no display.
It does boot, eventually, but the only correlation with my flailing efforts is that if I power down then remove and reinsert the power line, it often boots after 3 to 4 cycles.
Tried the systemd-analyze blame command (thanks Stephen) and got a list which I haven't yet found the top of, but it does show repeats in the time stamp.  The time starts at 170ms with snap-cantor-96.mount, snap-cantor-55.mount, snap-btop-598.mount,snap-btop-594.mount, snap-bare-5.mount, then
@182ms apport-autoreport.service, dev-loop44.device .... till @4.052s NetworManager-wait-online.service, lines 1-50 ...skipping..., then starts again @171ms.
Big gain in visibility for me, but don't know what to look for in this list. Should I load the list here?

Comment: **The way to not lose data is to have backups.** That said, you can safely  reinstall and keep `/home` because in a separated partition, you just have to know what you're doing. But if you knew you wouldn't be here asking, would you? So, again, do your backups.

Comment: Is this a new issue? Does it boot at all? Eventually? If so then once you've booted, open a terminal and run `systemd-analyze blame` to see where the hold up is. It could be you have some issue that will not be corrected by re-installing. Disks can have problems, network delays (local devices or your router)  can slow a boot to a crawl. So make sure you know what the problem is before you take a sledge hammer to it.

Comment: Whether or not the OS drive has any important data depends on what you consider important. If you want to keep certain configurations etc., then you may want to back up the `/etc` directory, for example.  It would also be good to know exactly what the issues are with booting to be able to say that 1) it can't easily be fixed without a reinstall, or 2) reinstalling won't fix it.